# HTML Form: List - Number of elements shown

Tags: html, forms, html-datalist

In my html form, I currently have a text input as follows:

```
<input list="BMUnits" name"BMUnitID" value"<?php echo $chosenBMU ?>" autocomplete="off">
<datalist id="BMUnits">
<option value="1">
...
<option value="300">
</datalist>
```

When the user types the drop down that shows the datalist goes off the screen, is there a way to define a certain number of elements in the datalist to be shown at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible. The current `<datalist>` tag does not support any special HTML attribute nor you can use CSS to style the dropped list. This means that only the browser can decide how the dropped list will look like. For example, IE (now called MS Edge) will show a scrollbar if the list is too long, but chrome won't. All we can do is waiting until browsers support that.

Alternativly, you can use jQueryUI [Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for more flexible drop list.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Basically wanted a field that showed the BMUnits as they typed, making it easier for the user. This is due to there being 300+ of them, nobody can remember that many!